# 2 MainActivities, manifest can't seem to differentiate them

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

So I got the AmazeFileManager source code from the GitHub and inside the `src` folder, there are 3 folders:

`fdroid`

`main`

`play`

Inside the `fdroid` and `play` there are 2 files, both named `MainActivity.java`. The rest of the code is inside the `main` folder.

After building this project inside Android Studio, I get no gradle errors, but when trying to run it, one of the classes points out that the object referencing the `MainActivity.java` class is missing. These two `MainActivity.java` files aren't the same, and the project is loading the one from `fdroid` folder as its main activity while the file from folder `play` is nowhere to be found within the project structure inside the studio.

How can I reference this other `MainActivity.java` inside the manifest?

Comment: Try using fully qualified names like `<action android:name="com.yourpackage.play.MainActivity" />

Comment: Thing is, once the build is complete, Android Studio unifies these 3 folders and only makes a reference for one of these `MainActivity` files, meaning that kind of reference still points to that same activity.

Comment: Could you link to this project source repo?

Comment: https://github.com/arpitkh96/AmazeFileManager